# How to use rollback with JDBCTemplate of springboot

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate, rollback

For insert operation in below code, the insert query executed successfully but the update query threw an exception.

**Expected result** : in case of any exception, even if insert query successfully executed, that transaction should be rolled back and no updating should happen as update query throwing exception.

**Actual Result** : transaction for insert query getting auto committed and nothing happens to update query(as here exception is being thrown)

***Please help me to achieve the expected result.***

Here is my code

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@Component("productDao")
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    HttpSession httpSession;

@Override
public boolean manageDBOperation(String operation, Data dataFromUser) {
        UserData userSessionData = (UserData) httpSession.getAttribute("userDetailsData");
        if(null != userSessionData) {
            int status = 0;
            int status1 = 0;
                        
            switch (operation) {
            
            case "INSERT":
                
                try {
                    try {                       
                        status1 = jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
                            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(MySqlQueries.INSERT_QUERY);                          
                            ps.setString(1, var1);
                            ps.setString(2, var2);
                            ps.setString(3, var3);                          
                            return ps;
                        });
                        // return status1 != 0;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.error("Error in inserting ==== ", e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (status1 != 0) {
                        try {
                            status = jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
                                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(MySqlQueries.UPDATE_QUERY);
                                ps.setString(1, var1);
                                ps.setString(2, var2);
                                ps.setString(3, var3);                              
                                return ps;
                            });
                            return status != 0;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            logger.error("Error in updating ==== ", e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Error in " + operation + " operation ==== ", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
                
            case "UPDATE":
                
                try {
                    try {
                        status1 = jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
                            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(MySqlQueries.UPDATE_QUERY1);
                            ps.setString(1, var1);
                            ps.setString(2, var2);
                            ps.setString(3, var3);
                            
                            return ps;
                        });
                        // return status1 != 0;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.error("Error in updating ==== ", e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (status1 != 0) {
                        try {
                            status = jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
                                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(MySqlQueries.UPDATE_QUERY2);
                                ps.setString(1, var1);
                                ps.setString(2, var2);
                                ps.setString(3, var3);
                                
                                return ps;
                            });
                            return status != 0;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            logger.error("Error in ==== ", e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Error in " + operation + " operation ==== ", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
                
            case "DELETE":
                
                try {
                    try {
                        status1 = jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
                            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(MySqlQueries.DELETE_QUERY);
                            ps.setString(1, var1);
                            ps.setString(2, var2);
                            ps.setString(3, var3);
                            
                            return ps;
                        });
                        // return status1 != 0;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        logger.error("Error in deleting ==== ", e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (status1 != 0) {
                        try {
                            status = jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
                                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement( MySqlQueries.UPDATE_QUERY);
                                ps.setString(1, var1);
                                ps.setString(2, var2);
                                ps.setString(3, var3);
                                
                                return ps;
                            });
                            return status != 0;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            logger.error("Error in updating ==== ", e);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Error in " + operation + " operation ==== ", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
                
            default:
                logger.warn("No Matched Operation found");
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one `Configuration` class like below

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("YOUR_BASE_PATH")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyConfig{
    @Bean(name = "MyDataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource getMyDataSource() {
        //return your data source by reading userName, password, url
        return dataSource;
    }

 //By using above data source create a Entity Manager factory like below
    
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "myEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean yccEntityManagerFactory1(@Qualifier("MyDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = initializeEntityManagerFactory(dataSource);
        emf.setPackagesToScan("YOUR_PACKAGE_TO_SCAN");
        return emf;
    }
//By using entity Manager Factory cretae a transactionManager like below

    @Bean(name = "myTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager seedTransactionManager(@Qualifier("myEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}



private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean initializeEntityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
        emf.setPersistenceProviderClass(org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        emf.setJpaProperties(properties);
        return emf;
    }
```

Now we have to create a `MyTransaction` interface by passing `myTransactionManager` as a value

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD })
@Transactional(value="myTransactionManager", rollbackFor={Exception.class})
public @interface MyTransaction{

}
```

Usage :

Now you can use `@MyTransaction` on any class level where you want to have a rollback

```
@MyTransaction
public class MyService{
}
```

OR

```
@Transactional("myTransactionManager")
public class MyService{
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vinay Hegde, can we have a conversation on mail(bbehera277@gmail.com) as I still have some doubts ? I couldn't get what is "YOUR_BASE_PATH" and "YOUR_PACKAGE_TO_SCAN" and also will the "MyTransaction" interface be blank(i.e without any method) ?

Comment: @BimalBehera basically `YOUR_BASE_PATH` is your component scan and `YOUR_PACKAGE_TO_SCAN` is the path where your entities are created. MyTransaction will be blank . Did you tried ? Also if you dont want to create an empty interface then you can use  directly `myTransactionManager`  in service like `Transactional("myTransactionManager")`. We are creating an interface because it will give more options like which excetion you want roll back with  `rollbackFor` etc...

Comment: @BimalBehera Then dont create any interface use `@Transactional("myTransactionManager")` directly  in service.see updated answer. Also check are you using this import `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`

Comment: I was using this import `javax.transaction.Transactional` but after I changed to `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` the errors inside the `MyTransaction` interface gone but after adding `initializeEntityManagerFactory` method I'm getting error like `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.bimal.practice.config.DBConfigForMySQL] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@229f39]`_**(Note : I used like properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");**_

Comment: Are you have pom.xml ? by seeing this `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class` seems some jar is having conflict.

Comment: Yes, I've pom.xml and FYI i added two jars(spring-orm  & hibernate-core) for this DB configs as recommended by you.

**(Suggestion : Can we have a mail conversation for quicker resolve of this issue ? If Yes, please send me a mail on the given mail address in my 1st comment and after successful resolve I'll post the answer here with each and every details)**

Comment: @VinayHegde....that `IllegalStateException` error gone, but this whole idea is not working. is there any alternative or if I am missing anything can you please help me ?

Comment: @BimalBehera Sure. Check your mail.